# Which package do I need to import to use JPGEncoder in flash?

Tags: flash, package

```
var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(85);
var jpgStream:ByteArray = jpgEncoder.encode(bmpData);
```

The above is reporting error:

```
Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: JPGEncoder.
Call to a possibly undefined method JPGEncoder.
```

Comment: @phwd already answered your question, but when you need further instructions, this blog post might interest you: http://henryjones.us/articles/using-the-as3-jpeg-encoder

Comment: @nikc, almost there,but I'm really new to flash, seems something is missing when I try to import that package...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you talking about

```
com.adobe.images.JPGEncoder; ?
```

If so,This is from the core classes in [ActionScript 3 Core Library](http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/).

**Edit** : The only other I know of that may come prepackaged is

```
mx.graphics.codec.JPEGEncoder
```

Not sure how it matches up to the as3core library

Comment: Thanks! This time I get: `Definition com.adobe.images:JPGEncoder could not be found.` How to include the core classes?

Comment: Well you need to download it http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/ I posted the link above here it is again.

Comment: Still can't access `com.adobe.images::JPGEncoder/encode()` :( It passes compilation but fails at run time.

Comment: Are the files you downloaded in your classpath?

Comment: @nikc, I just put the `com` directory under the the same directory my `.fla` is in. That should work, right?

Comment: @ieplugin I tried @nikc blog link and got it running on my localhost after publishing with Flash CS3 I encountered the same error and placed my com folder on the same level as my fla file. Could you list your Flash IDE and Flash Player version also if possible try to go through the blog example that @nikc provided maybe there is something you are over-looking. Is your code in a Document Class or a Frame ? What is the failure ? Run it debug and update the question? Sorry for all the questions. Just trying to define your problem :)