# Flash doesnt recognise JPGEncoder

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

When I run this code

```
var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(100);
```

It returns this error

> Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: JPGEncoder.
>       Call to a possibly undefined method JPGEncoder.

Flash doesn't recognise "JPGEncoder" as a keyword.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which package do I need to import to use JPGEncoder in flash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167636/which-package-do-i-need-to-import-to-use-jpgencoder-in-flash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPGEncoder is not a keyword, but a class you'll need to import to utilize.

Download JPGEncoder from [as3corelib](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib) and import it into your program using

```
import com.adobe.images.JPGEncoder;
```

Comment: Which ones should i download? Where should i put my download? Can you guide me to achieve this?

Comment: Download the entire package, or just JPGEncoder and its dependencies. Place the "com" folder wherever your source files are.

Comment: There is typo it should be like; import com.adobe.images.JPGEncoder;